# ToolStrip with ToolStripDropDownButton inside looks weird

Tags: winforms, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown

I have two versions of a Windows Forms Application and can't figure for the life of me how to get a particular GUI behavior to be the same without copying the entire code (which is an obvious no-no).

Here is a visual comparison:

[image]

The left one is the one I want to fix so that it looks like the right one. Notice how the ToolStrip looks as if it contained an extra ToolStripDropDownButton, or some property or style I don't know about was set to make it look like that.

I've been diff'ing like crazy and couldn't find what differs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. In the left side case, the button was "overflowing". Its size was too large to fit the toolstrip and thus it was collapsed like that. After adjusting the button's size in the left side, all was good.

I found out what was going on after reading basic stuff about toolstrip controls [here](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/creating-toolbars), in the "Using the CanOverflow and Overflow Properties" section.